# Magento 2 sales_order_invoice_pay fired on order placed

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I need sales_order_invoice_pay as observer for add some amount after first order invoiced.
But this observer fired when order placed. Did we have any Magento bug or am going wrong?

```
 <event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
    <observer name="reagent_add_amount_wallet" instance="Company\Reagent\Observer\AddAmountToWallet"/>
</event>
```

Comment: Are you using any payment gateway? Bacause third party payment gateway has options for invoice creation after payment. So may be this is the issue as you are using the right event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try event `controller_action_postdispatch_sales_order_invoice_save` if you want to execute your code after invoice generation from admin.